# One of two instances not getting initialized

Tags: c++, oop, ncurses

I am working with ncurses and i am trying to create a class that will print a box.
My class

```
class CMenu{
public:
    CMenu( int x , int y){
        this -> x = x;
        this -> y = y;
        createMenu();
    }   
    void createMenu(){
        start_color();
        cbreak();
        noecho();
        keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
        my_menu_win = newwin(30, 60, x, y);
        keypad(my_menu_win, TRUE);


    /* Print a border around the main window and print a title */
        box(my_menu_win, 0, 0);

        mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F2 to exit");
        refresh();
        wrefresh(my_menu_win);

        while(true){
            switch(c = wgetch(my_menu_win)){
                case KEY_F(2):
                    endwin();
                    exit(1);    
                case KEY_DOWN:
                    break;
                case KEY_UP:
                    break;
                case 10: 
                    move(20, 0);
                    clrtoeol();
                    wrefresh(my_menu_win);
                    refresh();
                    break;
            }
            wrefresh(my_menu_win);
        }
    }

private:
    int n_choices;
    int i;
    int index;
    int c;
    int x;
    int y;
    WINDOW *my_menu_win;

};
```

---

And class where I want to create instance of said class

```
class CUI{
public:
    CUI(){
        min_X = 200;
        min_Y = 50; 
    }

    void printBackground(){
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_GREEN,COLOR_BLACK);
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        mvhline( (y/5) - 1, (x/6),  ACS_BOARD , 140);
        mvhline( (y/5)*4, (x/6), ACS_BOARD , 140);
    }

    void initMenu(){    
        initscr();

        printBackground();
        left  = new CMenu(10,35);
        right = new CMenu(10,115);

        refresh();
        endwin();
}
private:
    int min_X;
    int min_Y;
    int x;
    int y;

    CMenu *left;
    CMenu *right;
};
```

And main

```
int main() {
    CUI one;
    one.initMenu();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that only one of the box gets printed. I added `cout` to a constructor of a CMenu class to see if both of them gets invoked. Only one of the instance gets invoked the second one gets ingored. What is causing this? Why arent both instances being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created the first menu (`left  = new CMenu(10,35);`), its constructor called `createMenu()`...and this one starts an infinite loop (`while(true)` statement) that will never end.

So the second menu won't be created. `right = new CMenu(10,115);` statement will never be reached...untill `CMenu::createMenu()` returns... and by reading your code there's apparently no action that will exit this loop. So your program will never create more than one `CMenu` instance...